# Windows 8 Store App Grid DataContext Refresh Programatically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, windows-8.1

I am setting the GridView Data Context in XAML similar to so:

```
<Grid x:Name="pageGrid">
        <Grid.DataContext>
            <local:ViewModel/>
        </Grid.DataContext>
</Grid>
```

This "ViewModel" class is a static class that is fill during:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    FillViewModel():
}
```

This allows for the view model to bound on screen load which works.

However, I want to load `FillViewModel` after the `MainPage` has initially ran.

Is there a way to programatically refresh the pageGrid XAML databinding? I have to be just missing it.

Answer (score -1):

**However, I want to load FillViewModel after the MainPage has initially ran.**

Sounds like your looking for the MainWindow / Control "Loaded" Event.

XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="Grid1" Loaded="Grid1_Loaded"/>
```

Code Behind:

```
private void Grid1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Do Stuff
}
```

Comment: no this isn't what i was going for. I need to essentially refresh page gridview data context

Comment: Did you bind the context to the target object? That way you wont need to worry about it. well, Thats what I would do.